# Split php function

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to split the following code.

```
<?php echo $currencySymbol." ".str_replace(",","",$custom_area1['mrp']); ?>
```

Currently it shows at **$ 100** for example

The $ I understand is coming from     `<?php echo $currencySymbol." ".`
While the amount is coming from     `str_replace(",","",$custom_area1['mrp'])`

How do I split it up so there is a function for **$** and a function for the **amount**.

Comment: What do you mean by split up function ?

Comment: so right now by using this 
<?php echo $currencySymbol." ".str_replace(",","",$custom_area1['mrp']); ?>

It shows $ 100

I want two functions from the above function to show the $ and 100 separately

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getCurrencySymbol(){
  return $currencySymbol;
}
public function getAmount(){
  $amount = str_replace(",","",$custom_area1['mrp']);
  return $amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`<?php echo $currencySymbol;?>`

```
<?php echo str_replace(",","",$custom_area1['mrp']); ?>/>
```